# Modifying the attribute of an object using a class method in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use a method defined in a class to later modify an attribute of an object made from that class, but there appears to be a scope problem that is not obvious to me. Take the following code:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute
    def change_attrib(self, attribute, value):
        if attribute + value < 0: attribute = 0
        else: 
            attribute += value
            print(str(attribute) + ' This is inside the method')

test1 = Test(10)

print(str(test1.attribute) + " This is before running the method")

test1.change_attrib(test1.attribute, 10)

print(str(test1.attribute) + " This is after running the method")

test1.attribute += 20

print(str(test1.attribute) + " This is after modifying the attribute directly")
```

Running this code produces the following result:

```
10 This is before running the method
20 This is inside the method
10 This is after running the method
30 This is after modifying the attribute directly
```

So it appears that even though I am explicitly referring to the instance that I want to change when calling the method, everything that happens in the method, stays in the method.

I can see that modifying the attribute directly works, but I would like a guard against negative values (hence the method). I also know I can use the built-in setattr() function within the method, and that works as well, but requires that I change the syntax for the attribute to a string before passing it into the method, and I much prefer explicitly referring to the attribute. Finally, I'd really just like to understand what is going on here.

EDIT:
This is the working code, based on the hint from rdvdev2. I just needed to reference self to set the instance's value:

```
class Test:
def __init__(self, attribute):
    self.attribute = attribute
def change_attrib(self, attribute, value):
    if attribute + value < 0: attribute = 0
    else: 
        attribute += value
        self.attribute = attribute
        print(str(attribute) + ' This is inside the method')
```

Also thanks to kindall for the great explanation of what was happening.

And a final expansion: The code above actually only works if the attribute is named attribute. I think kindall had the better grasp of what I needed here; in order for the function to be used to modify any attribute of the object, I need some way to reference the needed attribute. Since python appears to be passing a value instead of a reference, I have to get the reference somehow, and the least impactful way to my existing code appears to be using get/setattr....so I broke out regex and changed 160+ references.

Comment: Check getters and setters methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass in `test1.attribute` to `change_attrib()`, the value of `attribute` inside the method is not a pointer to `test1.attribute` that can be used to change its value. It is the integer 10. You then add the parameter `value` to `attribute`, yielding `attribute` equal to 20. Then the method ends and the value of `attribute` goes away. The value of `test1.attribute` never changed because you never changed it.

If you want your method to modify any attribute, you can pass its name as a string. You can then use `getattr()` and `setattr()` to get and set the attribute.

```
def change_attrib(self, name, value):
        attribute = getattr(self, name)
        if attribute + value < 0: attribute = 0
        else: 
            attribute += value
            print(str(attribute) + ' This is inside the method')
        setattr(self, name, attribute)

test1.change_attrib("attribute", 10)
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I already converted it to use getattr/setattr earlier, but I didn't understand why I needed that step. It does seem odd to me that it's passing the attribute into the method as an int rather than as an attribute of an object. 

I still am trying to find a way to use my original syntax for calling the method, though, as I've got a function very similar to this that's referenced hundreds of times that I'm not looking forward to changing.

Comment: You won't be able to use your original syntax, sorry. Python just doesn't work that way. All arguments are fully evaluated before being passed. `test1.attribute` evaluates to 10 so that's what your function sees. Think about it: suppose you passed in `test1.attribute + 10` instead. How would it even work in that case?

Comment: Yea, I eventually figured that out (see my edit above). It's really non-intuitive, since in cases where you pass an object, the object is referenced fine, and in cases outside of a method you can modify the attribute directly.

Answer (score 0):

In the class method you are modifying the `attribute` variable, wich is a function argument. If you want to modify the object attribute you have to access `self.attribute`

Comment: This answer actually got me where I needed to be. I'll post an edit with the code.